# Changing table column color based on value not working using jquery in razor file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, razor, model-view-controller

I read and tried many posts but get this working but unfortunately no luck so far.
I have a asp.net mvc project where I am trying to change the color of the column based on its value. For eg: if value is red apple change that column bg to red.

Below is my cshtml looks like:

```
 <body onload="changebgcolor()">           

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="fruit">
                   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fruit)
                </td>

                <td class="vege">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.vegetable)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
 </body>
```

And here is my script:

```
  function changebgcolor() {
    var table = $('#fruitsandveggies');
    $("tr.item").each(function () {
    var apple = $(this).find("td.fruit").text();

    if (apple == "RedApple")
    {
        $('.fruits').css('background', 'red');
    }
    if (apple == "GreenApple")
    {
        $('.fruits').css('background', 'green');
    }
});
```

}

I can see in it is returning apple == RedApple but it is not changing bg color to red or green for green apple. Same for the vege field. 
I couldn't figure out how to get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this it's working for me.

**I am created one demo for you.**

[image]

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <table>
            <tbody id="tablebody">          
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="fruit">
                           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fruit)
                        </td>

                        <td class="vege">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.vegetable)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Below code for script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $("#tablebody > tr").each(function (index,elem) 
    {       
        var apple = $.trim($(elem).find("td:first").text());
        if (apple == "RedApple")
        {
            $(elem).find("td:first").css('background', 'red');
        }
        else if (apple == "GreenApple")
        {
            $(elem).find("td:first").css('background', 'green');
        }   
    });
});
</script>
```